# Compare two files line by line and show only difference from file 2

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to compare two files line by line without sorting and show only difference from file2.

file `1.txt`:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
```

file `2.txt`:

```
one
five
three
four
five
twelve
seven
eight
hundred
ten
```

Then output should be

```
five 
twelve
hundred
```

I do not want to sort files.

Comment: Read `man comm`

Comment: `comm` will complain that order is not sorted.

Comment: I don't get it - why is `five` in the output if it's in both files?

Answer (score 4):

Doing line-by-line comparison using `awk`, you could do:

```
awk '{ getline x<"file2" } $0!=x{ print x}' file1
```

- `getline x<"file2"` reads the entire line from *file2* and holds into **x** variable.
- `print x` when line from file1 differ with line in file2.

Or same but shorter:

```
awk '{ getline x<"file1" } $0!=x' file2
```

Comment: Alternate implementation that does the same thing except it stores the first file in memory: `awk 'NR==FNR {line1[FNR] = $0; next} $0 != line1[FNR]' {1,2}.txt`

Answer (score 4):

You can as well use [`diff`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/diff.1.html) for that task:

```bsh
diff --old-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" 1.txt 2.txt
```

Gives the following output:

```bsh
five
twelve
hundred
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without sorting your data. Even if you never explicitly run the `sort` command, any solution *will* involving indexing or sorting the data and taking O(n) time or memory to do it. For example, a solution which goes through the files and keeps track of which lines are seen or not seen will take O(n) memory and a solution which sorts the files first will take O(n) time.